# LEFT JOIN freezes query execution

Tags: java, sybase

I have a pretty simple sql query:

```
SELECT  o.description, oi.description, cu.name
FROM dbo.order o 
LEFT JOIN dbo.orderitem oi o.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId
INNER JOIN dbo.customer cu on cu.customerId = o.customerId
WHERE cu.id = 12345
```

That query works, every time.

If I change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`...

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.customer cu on cu.customerId = o.customerId
```

then it always freezes when I call it with Java (via REST) and **sometimes** freezes if I am using my SQL Client. Sometimes it just works with the exact same search parameter and returns a few rows (<10) as expected.

Freezes means that it won't even start counting the execution time in my SQL client (SQuirreL) and that it will run into a timeout when I call it in Java.

But it will work again if I add a second WHERE clause like

```
SELECT  o.description, oi.description, cu.name
FROM dbo.order o 
LEFT JOIN dbo.orderitem oi o.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId
LEFT JOIN dbo.customer cu on cu.customerId = o.customerId
WHERE cu.id = 12345
AND o.someOtherId = 3456
```

or remove the cu.id completely.

Does anyone have any clue why that could happen?

Comment: Does the querry show up as a slow querry in the mysql log?

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting this line..

```
  LEFT JOIN dbo.orderitem am oi o.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId
```

Dont you think it should be like:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.orderitem oi on o.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId
```

Can you try?

Comment: Sorry, just a copy&paste error. The "am" is my actual alias, "oi" is the one I am using in the example.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the left join on `customer` makes the `where` clause ineffective; the query would return *all* `order`s, with *all* `orderitem`s, but only for `order`s of `customer` 12345, it would also return the `customer` name.

Maybe you want to do a `right join` instead, so you get the `customer` name even if he has no `order`s?

Comment: The query is actually to return all orders of a customer, I don't care for customers without orders in this case.

Comment: Then why the outer join? Keep the inner join.

Comment: Yes, the inner join will work, but I still would like to know why a left join crashes everything.

Comment: See my answer: The left join makes the query return all orders instead of just the orders for one customer; that's probably too much for good old sybase.

Comment: But why does it work sometimes for a query where it returns 9 rows?